# Read MD groups in QuickFixGo

Tags: go, quickfix, quickfixgo

How can I use the function:

https://github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/blob/master/field_map.go#L150

Has anybody got an example code snippet showing how to implement the `FieldGroupReader` interface?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you should be using one of the pre-defined implementation. Such as https://godoc.org/github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/fix44/massquote#NoPartyIDsRepeatingGroup

If you want to implement a non-standard group you can follow e.g. https://github.com/quickfixgo/quickfix/blob/102166066b60662e45cc963e405d281cd3e20101/fix44/massquote/MassQuote.generated.go#L3895